# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on React

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I am working on a project under CMS, I do not have any access to server.

so I downloaded below 4 files

> browser.min.js
>  jquery.min.js
>  react.js
>  react-dom.js
>   remarkable.min.js

and loaded on the html page. Everything works fine before I use import.

```
import { sample } from './sample';
```

Makes **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on React**

I am not able to install weback or Browserify on the server, so have to load from somewhere.

Anyone has got a solution for this?

Comment: You've got to give more context, such as your configuration. If you want to use ES6 syntax you'll need to transpile it to ES5. Also, you need a module library for `require`.

Comment:  You don't know [tag:npm] !!

Comment: I cannot access to server so cannot use npm...

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for.

```
<head>
 <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-
  dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
  core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: No. Sorry. Maybe not the answer. I think import and require require node.js or browserify.         

But perhaps you can achieve what you need using `React.createClass`
         
[link] (https://github.com/vasansr/react-tutorial-mern/blob/step-3.2/src/App.js)

Not sure what you're trying to do. You can use npm and install webpack locally and run a local server on your own computer.